# Returning a query string in ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Hi I am trying to to pass a query string to the link and I have writen it like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink(subcategory,"Index" , "Products" , new { category = subcategory})
```

The way I written it I recieve this and it seems it does not recognize the actionName:

```
http://localhost:2100/?Length=8
```

If I remove new { category = subcategory} I get this:

```
http://localhost:2100/Products
```

What I would like the ActionLInk to do is to return something like this:

```
http://localhost:2100/Products/Index?substring=9
```

Comment: subcategory is a c# variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the [wrong overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492124%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) of the `Html.ActionLink`. That is why the 3th argument `"Products"` gets interpreted as the route values which results `?Length=8` in the url.

As a sidenote: the `Length=8` is coming from the `string` type which has one property `Length` and the length of the `"Products"` string is 8.

So you just need to use [one of the correct overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972%28v=vs.108%29.aspx):

```
@Html.ActionLink(subcategory, //link text
                 "Index", //action name
                 "Products", //controller name
                 new { category = subcategory}, //route values
                 null // html attributes
                )
```